# Are my machine and my Java 32-bit or 64-bit?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, 32bit-64bit

Is my machine 32-bit or 64-bit? Is the Java installed in my machine 32-bit or 64-bit?

`uname -a` produces:

```
Linux xhost 2.6.18-194.el5xen #1 SMP Tue Mar 16 22:01:26 EDT 2010 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

`java -version` produces:

```
java version "1.6.0_24"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_24-b07)
Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (build 19.1-b02, mixed mode)
```

Comment: The output shows you're running a 64-bit version of Linux (note the `x86_64` in the output of `uname -a`) and a 32-bit version of Java.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`java -version` will look like this on a 64 bit VM (it explicitly says 64 bits):

```
java version "1.7.0_07"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_07-b10)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.3-b01, mixed mode)
```

Comment: Also, the machine is 64-bit, as `uname` reports x86_64.

Answer (score 2):

You can try `java -d64 -version`

if it's not 64 bit, you'll get something like that :

`This Java instance does not support a 64-bit JVM.`
`Please install the desired version`

Comment: Perhaps my Java is too old, but I only see "Unrecognized option: -d64"